# Azure Data Factory Pipeline Logs

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Where does data logs of Azure Pipeline v2 gets stored, I would like to retrieve data of failed pipelines for specific date.( Dont want to use azure portal to view these data). Is there any table/view holds such datalogs  from database.

Comment: Azure Pipeline? You mean Azure Data Factory or something else?

Comment: Were any of the provided answers helpful or need any further elaboration?  Please provide feedback as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, to obtain diagnostic logs you can use [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor), [Operations Management Suite (OMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-monitor-oms), or monitor those pipelines [visually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-visually).

Answer (score 0):

By Azure Pipeline v2, you mean Azure Data Factory v2. [Alert and Monitor data factories using Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor)

[Diagnostic logs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#diagnostic-logs)

- Save them to a Storage Account for auditing or manual inspection. You can specify the retention time (in days) using the diagnostic settings.
- Stream them to Event Hubs for ingestion by a third-party service or custom analytics solution such as PowerBI.
- Analyze them with Log Analytics

Answer (score 0):

The logs are stored on Azure Data Factory web server for 45 days. If you want to get the pipeline run and activity run metadata, you can use Azure Data Factory SDK to extract the information you need and save it somewhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended approach on this for log term analysis as well as limiting access to a production data factory would be to configure logs to be sent to log analytics. Be sure to enable dedicated logging tables as this will help on the backend in terms of organizing your logs.

From there you can also set up alerts and access groups running off of log analytics queries for better monitoring.